# How to find the class name & title of a program in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, class, title

The question is how to find the class name from running programs and title of those programs. I know there already exist some scanning tools like `WinDowse` or [`spy++`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment) from visual studio, but what I am asking you is how to make programs like those in our own source code, what function to use, is there some open source program that can help? Code appreciated, link's also :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Use [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all top-level windows and get their handle.
2. Pass the handle to [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the window title and window class respectively.

Example:

```
EnumWindows(EnumProc, 0);

...

BOOL CALLBACK EnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
  TCHAR title[256];
  TCHAR className[256];

  GetWindowText(hWnd, title, 256);
  MessageBox(NULL, title, NULL, MB_OK);

  GetClassName(hWnd, className, 256);
  MessageBox(NULL, className, NULL, MB_OK);

  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: @raptor: Just to let you know, I added a `return TRUE` to the above code that I had forgotten previously.