# How to Show windows side by side from c++?

Tags: c++, windows, window, switch-statement

everyone the question is how to use options Show windows side by side by side from c++? I use windows 7 professional, 64 bit, is there some function that can be used, to switch widow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this yourself.  Work out the coordinates of the windows based on the size of the work area. Divide the width by 2 and do the math.  There are no in-built shortcuts.

I don't understand your other question about switching window.

Comment: can you put some code how to select all the windows and than position it on he screen? Sometime is more than two windows on screen ....

Comment: c++ is a little too generic: are you programming with MFC ? do you "own" the window you need to place, or are they from other executables ?

Comment: they are from other executables

Comment: `FindWindow` or `EnumerateWindows` will get you some HWNDs. Then call `SetWindowPos`. To find out about the monitor sizes use `EnumMonitors` and its friends.

Comment: For example you could use the code from the answer to [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727135/) which I not you have not accepted

Comment: Based on your comments, it would just be easier for you to right click the taskbar and select "Show Windows side by side".

Answer (score 0):

If you own the window use the famous SetWindowPos function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx